# Importing customers to magento website

Tags: magento, csv, import, passwords

I am importing customers from old website to magento. While importing via CSV file, I get the following error:

Invalid password length in rows: 36, 42, 54, 142, 160, 219, 298, 341, 352, 376, 428, 430, 460, 481, 510, 511, 535, 561, 565, 570, 588, 601, 661, 672, 701, 727, 774, 779, 847, 865, 876, 892, 912, 924, 932, 943, 951, 952, 953, 972, 988, 1017, 1022, 1030, 1059, 1068, 1091, 1147, 1150, 1153, 1155, 1156, 1157, 1158, 1161, 1162, 1163, 1165, 1167, 1175, 1177, 1178, 1179, 1180, 1181, 1183, 1187, 1188, 1189, 1190, 1191, 1197, 1198, 1199, 1200, 1201, 1203, 1207, 1210, 1211, 1212, 1219, 1224, 1225, 1254, 1268, 1279, 1290, 1301, 1302, 1304, 1322, 1332, 1342, 1367, 1378...

How can I remove this validation in magento programmatically or is there any easier way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the validation both programmatically as on frontend, otherwise a user has a short pass but can't log in due to javascript validation.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/18197/